# How to evaluate this expression: $ \ 3^{\log_4 5} + 4^{\log_5 3} - 5^{\log_4 3} - 3^{\log_5 4} \ $

Tags: logarithms

How to evaluate this expression?

$$ \ 3^{\log_4 5} + 4^{\log_5 3} - 5^{\log_4 3}  - 3^{\log_5 4} \ $$

Comment: Hint: $\;a^{log_b(c)} = c^{log_b(a)}\,$.

Comment: How? Is it any specific theorem?

Comment: Take the $\log$ on both sides and use that $\log_u(v)=\log(v) / \log(u)\,$.

Comment: Where are the two sides? This is just an expression. Can I equate it to 0 ?

Comment: I was referring to the equality in my previous comment.

Comment: $$ 3^{\log_4 5} = \left( 4^{\log_4 3} \right)^{\log_4 5} = 4^{(\log_4 3 \cdot \log_4 5)} = \left( 4^{\log_4 5} \right)^{\log_4 3} = 5^{\log_4 3}. $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very often when you encounter an expression like $g(x)^{f(x)}$ you would want to to rewrite it as $e^{f(x)\ln(g(x))}$.

Also, remember that $\log_a(b) = \frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$.

With that in mind:
$3^{\log_4(5)} = e ^ { \frac{\ln(5) }{ \ln(4)} \ln(3) } $
and same is for
$5^{\log_4(3)} = e ^ { \frac{\ln(3) }{ \ln(4)} \ln(5) } $ so they cancel each other.

Same is for other two summands. So the whole expression evaluates just to zero.

Comment: Good answer with complete explanation, keep it up. +1 :)